# How to display query result table with grids in Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with table grids in Oracle SQL Developer. It has not been set with grids by default. How to display sql tables with grids? Now I have attributes separated by spaces and attributes are separated from value fields by "----".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you are using *run script(`F5`)* That's why you are seeing the result like that. 
Select(highlight) all or only the code blocks or statements you want to execute and then execute it with *run statement (`Ctrl+Enter`)*

Comment: Ctrl+Enter or F9 or the first button (green arrow) in the SQL Worksheet toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two different paths:

1. executing queries, seeing the results
2. displaying (sql) tables

[Null's answer takes care of #1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54291196/1156452).

For #2, you can open the actual table being used in your query quite easily.

[image]

Or you can just directly browse the list of tables and views for your schema or under 'Other Users' in the tree and click on them to open them. Or double-click if you have disabled 'open object on single click' in preferences.